# Android\Eclipse the for-each loop

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my code Android extract of java class and complete XML Android file:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                Log.i("myApp0", tokens[0].toString());
                Log.i("myApp1", tokens[1].toString());
                Log.i("myApp2", tokens[2].toString());

                profileImage.setImageUrl(tokens[0].toString());
                textData.setText(tokens[1].toString());
                textTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tokens[2].toString()));
                textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
```

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#444"
        android:padding="3dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textData"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"        
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think that the output for each row have the date and title of each photo albums but instead I've the same photo album for each row and in the layout android I've only first date and photo album... why?

```
04-09 18:38:11.088: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.088: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.088: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.178: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.178: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.178: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.188: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.188: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.188: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.188: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.198: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.198: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.198: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.208: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.208: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.208: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.208: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.208: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.218: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.218: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.218: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.228: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.238: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.238: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.238: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.248: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.258: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.258: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.258: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.268: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.268: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.268: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.288: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.288: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.288: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.298: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.308: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.308: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.308: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
04-09 18:38:11.318: I/myApp0(28558): https://Link1
04-09 18:38:11.318: I/myApp1(28558): 09/04/2013
04-09 18:38:11.318: I/myApp2(28558): <a href=http://Link1>Pics1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have this:

```
         Log.i("myApp0", tokens[0].toString());
            Log.i("myApp1", tokens[1].toString());
            Log.i("myApp2", tokens[2].toString());
```

You aren't using the iterator of i.. you're using the constant of 0,1,2 so it's always going to be outputting the same value all those times.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the i variable.

Lets see your code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            Log.i("myApp0", tokens[0].toString()); // is going to print always the same thing no matter how many rows this has
            Log.i("myApp1", tokens[1].toString());
            Log.i("myApp2", tokens[2].toString());

            profileImage.setImageUrl(tokens[0].toString()); //is always going to set the same image url
            textData.setText(tokens[1].toString());
            textTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tokens[2].toString()));
            textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
```

Are you sure you should use an array of strings? 
The best approach is to use an Object that has this elements:

```
public class Your_Obj {
    String date, profile_img, title;

//here you implement your object and generate the getters and setters
}
```

and use a List of objects like this:
instead of your tokens array you should use:

```
List<Your_obj> listYourObjects= getMyObj();

for(Your_Obj obj in listYourObjects){ 

                profileImage.setImageUrl(obj.getProfile_img);
                textData.setText(obj.getDate);
                textTitle.setText(obj.getTitle));
                textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}
```

Comment: Okay thank you but how to for show in android application for each row have the date and title of each photo albums ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length/3; i++) {
            Log.i("myApp0", tokens[i*3 + 0].toString());
            Log.i("myApp1", tokens[i*3 + 1].toString());
            Log.i("myApp2", tokens[i*3 + 2].toString());

            profileImage.setImageUrl(tokens[i*3 + 0].toString());
            textData.setText(tokens[i*3 + 1].toString());
            textTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tokens[i*3 + 2].toString()));
            textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
```

Tokens should be `Array` of `Object` instead of this. But you can achieve your desired output using this technique.

To show every record with its own `View`, you have to create `ListView` as illustrated in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

       private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater; 
       private ArrayList<String> yourData = new ArrayList<Entry>();

       public ImageListAdapter(Context context) { 
          mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
          return yourData.size()/3; // Specifically for your data -- Not recommended
       }

       @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {
          return yourData.get(position);
       }

       @Override
       public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView,
             ViewGroup parent) {                                        
          RelativeLayout itemView;
          if (convertView == null) {                                      
             itemView = (RelativeLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                      R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

          } else {
             itemView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
          }

          ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);                       
          TextView textTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);                      
          TextView textData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listDescription);                  

            profileImage.setImageUrl(tokens[i*3 + 0].toString());
            textData.setText(tokens[i*3 + 1].toString());
            textTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tokens[i*3 + 2].toString()));
            textTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

          return itemView;
       }

       public void upDateEntries(ArrayList<String> entries) {
          yourData = entries;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

Set this `Adapter` to your `ListView` by using `ListView.setAdapter(/* ImageListAdapter instance */);`

Inspired from [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/145373/android-listviews-with-dynamic-data/)

Comment: thank you with your suggestion show always first date and photo album

Comment: are you sure your data is different ?

Comment: I've only pic and only date of last album in layout android

Comment: You should also change that in your code... wait let me update my answer

Comment: Confirm I tried your code and I've only pic and only date of last album

Comment: You mean to say that same picture/date/last album is shown on every item ?

Comment: Not, I've only item with the picture/date of last album

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: I need show all items with the picture/date of all album's photos

Comment: You have to use ListView for that... Are you using that ?

Comment: No... you have any example/tutorial for dynamic ListView?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html hopefully this will help

Comment: thanks but this article use static string ListView ... and not use dynamic string as in my case